# Hololens 2 audio stream from Desktop

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, webrtc, audio-streaming, hololens

I'm currently developing an app for the HoloLens 2 that needs to stream audio from a desktop PC.
The idea is to send control information (position, orientation, etc.) to a Cycling'74 Max/Msp application running on a Windows 10 computer to process audio for 3D audio playback. I now need to somehow stream the resulting sound to the Unity app running on the HoloLens. Both devices run on the same network.

At the moment I've achieved something using mrtk webrtc for unity in combination with a virtual cable as input. My issue is that this seems to be optimized for microphone use as it applies some options like noise reduction and smaller bandwidth. I can't find a way to set the options for webrtc to stream what I need (music) with better quality.

Does anyone know how to change that on mrtk webrtc or has a better solution for the audio streaming to the hololens?

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC project for Mixed Reality is deprecated and it is designed for real-time communication. If your requirement is media consumption, you need other workaround solutions.

- For dedicated media streaming, you can set up a DLNA server on your PC for media access.
- You may also set up Samba or NFS on your PC if you need to access files in other formats.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer.
As the sound is created in real-time by Max MSP, no direct file is available and the need for real-time audio makes it difficult to first create and send a file. The overall need for this setup occurs specifically because I can't run Max Msp on ARM or ARM64, which is the architecture of the Hololens.

Comment: I am not an expert on Max MSP and am not sure about the capability of exporting formats. Is it for real-time local streaming or more like live streaming (with few seconds delay)? If it is for real-time, you need to convert the output data to something that suits Unity and transmission methods can be varied. While for live streaming, you may consider using Unity Video Stream Receiver or UWP Adaptive Streaming.